# How to decline https requests to certain domain (IIS 7.5)?

Tags: iis, ssl

I have 2 domains domain1.com and domain2.com hosted on IIS server, both point to one IP address. I have a SSl cert issued for domain1.com. How do I decline https://domain2.com request before user sees name mismatch certificate error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You need two IP addresses in order to make this work.

The HTTP `Host` parameter is what tells your server with virtual domain to use; it is "application data" and not sent until the SSL handshake (during which the server certificate is presented) has been completed.